# can’t inherit from superclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instantiation, superclass

I have a simple code like below where the class Employee should inherit from the class Person.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname
    self.age = age
  def getname(self):
    return self.firstname, self.lastname
  def getage(self):
    return self.age

class Employee(Person):
  def __init__(self, first, last, empid, age):
    Person.__init__(self, first, last, age):
    self.empid = empid
  def getemp(self):
return self.getname() + ", " + self.empid

employee = Employee("Bart", "Simpson", 1006, 16)
print(employee.getemp())
```

It gives me this error:

```
File "/tmp/pyadv.py", line 156
    Person.__init__(self, first, last, age):
                                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) about classes and it didn’t have that superclass initialization inside the `__init__()` of the subclass. But I found that in other websites like [here](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/), where Dog inherits from Pet.
So, what am I missing?

Comment: You have a spurious colon at the end of that line.

Comment: @kindall, ok, I hadn´t noticed that. But how is this off-topic???

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything. You need to get rid of the `:` on that line.

`:` only comes after the original definition ie: `def getname(self):` and is always followed by an indented line that declares the function. When you are calling a function you don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`Person.__init__(self, first, last, age):` to

`super().__init__(first, last, age)`